# Does the IE 10 browser have a shorter internal timeout than the Chrome browser?

Tags: asp.net, internet-explorer, google-chrome, httprequest, httpresponse

NOTE:  I'm using an IIS 7.5 server and asp.net

The reason I ask is because I have the httpRuntime time-out in my web application set to 10 hours, currently.  NOTE:  The ridiculously high timeout is for testing purposes!  This works beautifully for Chrome since it seems to have a much longer internal timeout than IE 10.  For my example, I'm compressing large files on the server before I start the streaming process.  This means the browser has to wait a certain amount of minutes before it starts receiving data from the web server.  For a 1.2 GB file, it takes about 7 minutes before the streaming process begins.  The Chrome browser can handle this fine.. after 7 minutes, the file starts downloading.  With IE 10, however, it just goes into infinite spin mode.   It can be an hour later and the streaming still hasn't occurred.  This tells me that there's obviously some sort of internal timeout difference between the two browsers.  Are there any http response codes I could send to the IE browser to force it to stay open longer?  Would appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0):

Relying on these kinds of wait periods is unwise, because they can change with each new version.

Why not have one call start the compression and have the browser poll the server after every 15s (or whate ever value) to see if compression is complete. When compression is complete then begin streaming. This pattern is quite easy to implement in JavaScript and on ASP.NET as well.

Comment: Actually, you just hit on my long term solution.  I'm planning to use SignalR, which acts similar to how long-polling works and is supposed to be far more efficient keeping connections open with IIS servers, etc.  This is more of a short term solution to get me by for now.

Comment: Also, the polling approach that you recommend won't work very well in my situation since we're on the cloud using Windows Azure.  That means there's multiple web server instances being shuffled around by the Load Balancer so there's no way to predict which active server has the compression process going on.  With SignalR, there's something called a "backplane" that deals with this situation.